# Model Edit Migration Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to edit a model to make the columns not null, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I created a migration file, wrote my desired changes, and ran db:migrate.

Migration File

```
class ChangeFieldsToNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_column :events, :event_name, :string, null: false
    change_column :events, :f1, :string, null: false
    change_column :events, :f2, :string, null: false
  end
end
```

Schema Result

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_04_20_233006) do
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "event_name", null: false
    t.string "f1", null: false
    t.string "f2", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

After making these changes I tried to submit all null entries into the database, and it went straight in with no issues. Why is the DB accepting null entries when I just added null:false to all attributes?

```
 #<Event:0x0000022826ff12e8 id: 2, event_name: "", f1: "", f2: "", created_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:39:10.196725000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:39:10.196725000 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Event:0x0000022826ff1220 id: 3, event_name: "", f1: "", f2: "", created_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:44:53.247575000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:44:53.247575000 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Event:0x0000022826ff1158 id: 4, event_name: "", f1: "", f2: "", created_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:50:50.998929000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 23:50:50.998929000 UTC +00:00>]
```

Edit***

Record Creation Method

```
class AddeventController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @event = Event.new
    end

    def create
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        
        if @event.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :f1, :f2)
    end

end
```

Comment: How are you creating these records - just `Event.create` with no arguments ?

Comment: I edited my post to show how it's being added (i submit a form and this handles it) I also did event = Event.new(event_name: "", f1: "", f2: "") and event.save

Comment: `null: false` only prevents you from saving nil/null values to the columns, not empty strings

Comment: i hate my life, thank you.